# Java Connection refused

Tags: java

I have the following simple code programmed to automatically enter data to a website. However, I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

I am using NetBeans.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;


public class ts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage( new URL("http://rise4fun.com/QuickCode") );
        final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm)page.getFormsByName("form1").get(0);
        final HtmlInput inp = form.getInputByName("SourceBox");
        inp.setValueAttribute("24.9.2011 | 24 Sep 2011\n8/15/2010");
         HtmlSubmitInput sub=(HtmlSubmitInput) page.getHtmlElementById("AskButton");
         page = (HtmlPage)sub.submit();   
         final String pageAsText = page.asText();
         HtmlElement out=page.getHtmlElementById("OutputBox");
         System.out.println(out.asText());

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to access the URL otherwise?

Comment: @Swapnil- Yes, I can access the URL

Answer (score 1):

Since I now know that you're behind a firewall, your Java code has to define the proxy before you can access the Internet.

```
URL url = new URL("http://rise4fun.com/QuickCode");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxy);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

Another way of coding for a proxy is:

```
URL url = new URL("http://rise4fun.com/QuickCode");
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy ip", 8080));
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(proxy);
```

Comment: does'nt help... m not able to access any website at all

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: No, I have allowed Netbeans through my firewall

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you're behind a firewall, you must code for a proxy in your Java code.

Comment: There is no proxy related error as I can access webpages using another api (selenium). However, it doesnot work with HTMMLUnit